# Replace multiple lines in a file not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to edit the build.prop file by replacing 3 lines in the file. The following method leaves the original lines and copies the new ones to the new file. I need to replace the lines instead of adding new.

I've updated my code to use the "else if" shown below

```
/**Changing build.prop values here
* @throws IOException */

public void PropEdit() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
String origFile = "data/data/vzw.versatile1.props/build.orig.prop";
String propFile = "data/data/vzw.versatile1.props/build.new.prop";
try {
suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data/data/vzw.versatile1.props/build.new.prop\n");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(origFile));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(propFile));

String line; 
String params [];

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
params = line.split("=");  
if 
(params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.device")) {
out.println(params[0] + "=" + "Maguro");
/**out.println(line); **/
out.flush();
} else
if 
(params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.name")) 
{ 
out.println(params[0] + "=" + "yakju");
/**out.println(line); **/
out.flush();
} else if (params[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ro.product.model")) 
{
out.println(params[0] + "=" + "Galaxy Nexus");
/**out.println(line); **/
out.flush();
}
out.println(line);
}
boolean successful;
{
out.close();
in.close();
os.flush();
os.close();
suProcess.waitFor();

}   
} catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'with the params[]'?

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far!

Comment: @Versatile1 You implementation looks allright, So where is the problem? May be it will help if you show both files and your expected output.

Comment: I will grab the rest of the code and files/output when I get home. The problem is when I try to add more lines it loops but doesnt throw an error. I have a cath for all 3 lines so I don't understand.

Comment: @Versatile1 "You mean you need to process only the first three lines." you mean you want to replace the thing only in the first 3 lines, right? I'm kinda confused...

Comment: @Versatile1 ok. i think i got your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: If I understand you correctly, this should do it:

```
//your while loop
// if you have exact 3 cases, you can do this.
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    params = line.split("="); 
    if ("ro.device.name".equalsIgnoreCase(params[0])) {
        out.println(params[0] + "=" + "Galaxy Nexus"); 
    } else if ("ro.device.product".equalsIgnoreCase(params[0])) {
        out.println(params[0] + "=" + "some String"); 
    } else if ("ro.device.whatever".equalsIgnoreCase(params[0])) {
        out.println(params[0] + "=" + "another String"); 
    } else {
        out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Maybe you have problem with case sensitive. You can try

```
"ro.device.name".equalsIgnoreCase(params[0])
```

Or, I think replaceAll is also good for this kind of task.

```
line = line.replaceAll("(?i)" + "ro.device.name=Galaxy Nexus",);
```

Or

```
public static void replace(String oldstring, String newstring, File in, File out)
throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(out));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        writer.println(line.replaceAll("(?i)" + oldstring,newstring));
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

***Note "(?i)" is for ignore case.***

Comment: I actually have the .equalsIgnoreCase(params[0]) in use I fought that battle already :) but thank you

Comment: @Versatile1 alright, please see my edit. hope i understand you correctly this time.

Comment: The edits you suggested worked great. The only issue is the original line remains after the method writes the new line

Comment: @EntryLevelDev21 any idea why it is copying instead of replacing?

Comment: Could you show your log? what's printed out?

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
if ("ro.device.name".equals(params[0]))
    out.println(params[0] + "=" + Galaxy Nexus); 
} else {
    out.println(line);
}
```

To (note the `{` at the end of the `if` line:

```
if ("ro.device.name".equals(params[0])) {
    out.println(params[0] + "=" + Galaxy Nexus); 
} else {
    out.println(line);
}
```